# How do I react when a girl I like has a new haircut that I don't like very much?

Tags: friends, europe, gender

I've had a past teenage experience (~10 years ago) where a girl I liked (only friends) asked me about whether I liked her fake nails. I answered honestly and say I didn't like them at all and prefer natural nails, to which she was very upset. I tried to justify myself by saying how an honest opinion is always better - but it only made her more upset. This was a bad, however very life-instructing experience - that in some cases saying my opinion too straight was not the greatest idea.

Since then it has happened to me twice that girls I like (only friends) have got a major haircut, and this is going to happen a 3rd time (I only saw a picture so far). In one of those cases I was explicitly asked about whether I liked the short hair, and in order to avoid a repeat of the earlier bad experience I had with the fake nails, I felt forced to lie and said I like it - which felt extremely awkward since I normally never lie, and it was probably obvious I was thinking the opposite, which made me feel even worse for lying.

As a person, my behaviour is that I usually say what I think straightly and loudly, no matter if it pleases other people or not because that's how I am and hiding my real feelings only complicate things. My previous life experience taught me that wanting to hide things and being politically correct is counter-productive, and being straight and honest is more efficient.

**While I like my friends no matter how they look externally**, I clearly prefer girls with long hair. Unfortunately, I only have bad choices as how to react:

- If I say I like the new hairstyle I'm outright lying and that's a terrible choice.
- If I say straight I don't like it, they'll be upset and it'll repeat my past negative experience.
- If I ignore the matter completely and act as if nothing happened/as if I didn't notice the style change, it means I do not care about her or how she looks and that's not a very good thing either.

No matter how hard I think I cannot find a behaviour that is exemplary in this case. If it matters for this question, I'm a guy.

Comment: Do you still find them physically attractive with shorter hair?

Comment: @JMac Well, for the case that made me ask in question I only saw a pic so far, I didn't see her personally yet, hence while it make sense to ask this in order to be prepared for the next time we met and I actually see it for real.

Comment: A major problem with this question, and why it's attracting so many conflicting answers, is that you don't state what relationship you have.  Are you acquaintences through work or some other group/organization? Are you friends? Have you dated in the past?  Might you date in the future?  Are you actively seeing each other? Dating? Married?  The answer is different based on your relationship, not whether you like them or not.  You need to know why they are asking in general, and why they are asking you specifically, and your relationship status changes how you should respond.

Comment: @AdamDavis It's just friends that I *might* data in the future, nothing more. AKA "Just Friends TM"

Comment: We are tagging your question "switzerland" because that is how we do things here. We need to classify questions by where they are so that you get the best answers. Your culture may affect what the appropriate answer is. Someone in China or the US may disagree about the solution - what is important is that the solution is tailored to you and you are in Switzerland, so we tag the question as such.

Comment: @Catija I disagree. The goal is not to answer the question only for my specific case, which is my private matter, but also other people who happens to have similar cases. Stackexchange is about databases of questions/answer pairs, not discussion forum. So where I live does not matter - if it matters then it should be mentionned in the answers. I regret mentionning it at all - I should've always left it out entierely and ignored comments prompting for that info.

Comment: That is how this site works. Questions must be about a specific problem that you face, otherwise they are too broad. Please see our meta discussions on this topic : https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/related-answers-why-your-pakistani-answer-wont-always-work-for-india and https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/233/36 As such, we could have several questions that ask the same thing, but for different cultures.

Comment: @Bregalad if you had not provided this info, the question would have been closed. Note that if the answers to this question are actually applicable to someone living in, say, China, a question with the China tag can always be closed as a duplicate of a question with the Switzerland tag.

Comment: @Catija Seeing the answers it seems my quesiton actually **was** not too board but opinion based, so it couldv'e been closed. I can imagine China or India would be different - but in any 1st world "western" country it shouldn't make any cultural difference.

Comment: [Highly relevant video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxMwWmPXpMk)

Comment: I've closed this question as Too Broad. As @Catija said, location tags are almost always needed in questions on Interpersonal Skills to limit answers to only one culture. I would have added the [tag:switzerland] tag back in after you removed it, but given that the answers so far haven't taken culture into account, it wouldn't particularly help.

Comment: I think that this is an issue that all cultures can have, and thus the Switzerland tag is not necessary. The too broad tag does not apply here. There is a very specific question asked and honestly, I am uncomfortable with the fact that 2 people can close a question.

Comment: @JoeS Well apparently they close it as a "retailation" for my refusal of having it tagged "Switzerland". Who cares, there's enough answers already (a bit too much actually). Answers have shown that this is primarly opinion based, but not too board. So it's normal the question gets closed but it gets it for the wrong reason. Well, usual SE stuff.

Comment: [Related meta question.](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1401/102)

Comment: Good edits. You should also add what kind of relationship you are looking for with such girl(s). Acquaintance, friend, girlfriend, or future spouse will require different considerations. The more serious the relationship, the more important it is to consider the other persons feelings rather than just your own.

Comment: @user3169 Sorry but this is purely private and personal and not the matter of other stackoverflow users. I am only partially anonymous here.

Comment: Post edits . . . I think this is a better question. It would be nicer to have a more specific location tag, but the added information narrows down things about the relationship nicely. I'm voting to reopen this.

Comment: @HDE226868 Glad you like the edit. Originally I tried to simplify/summarize the situation, but did it poorly and I guess it desserved me in the end.

Comment: @Catija About the Switzerland tag: you're aware that there are 4 official languages (if you want to define culture by language) in Switzerland and the usual contrast between rural and urban areas, etc.? I think specific country is a red herring in this case...

Comment: This urgently needs a country tag. Politeness vs honesty differs so widely between countries that any answer will be wrong in half of the world (but with the US-centric userbase it won't be reflected in the votes).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So, to give an answer that is not "lie, or move around the subject" here is my version: **be honest**.

If you don't like it, don't start about it, but when she brings up the subject you're totally fine to actually tell the truth. You don't have to say you find her new style the worst in the world, but there is nothing wrong with admitting that you preferred her previous style.

If she's asking you what you think about it, she wants your opinion. Not some lie or evasive answer (and beware, she will understand that you don't like it if you ignore her real question). Better be honest than pretending you really like it, when she finds out it makes it even worse.

Comment: Welcome to Interpersonal Skills! I invite you to take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about the site and its guidelines. Are these mere suggestions? Have you had any similar or related experiences? :)

Comment: "If she's asking you what you think about it, she wants your opinion." I audibly laughed at this naive statement. Most people I know have been looking for confirmation that their decision was a good one, not for honest feedback.

Comment: I agree, and I think there's something important here that a lot of people don't get: when someone asks you for your opinion, they're hoping you have a good one. if you always say you have a good opinion, they can never believe you, and your answer becomes hollow and fake. it's still worse to not like it - but lying hurts your ability to be honest about positive opinions later.

Comment: also, people are often asking "do you approve of my existence?" when they ask for feedback on themselves - try to be honest about whether you approve of their existence at the same time as being honest about this small thing you're sharing your thoughts on.

Comment: You can be honest and still be polite: it's very modern but I think I liked it better before.

Answer (score 89):

I've been on the other side of this and I agree that lying is not a great idea. She'll know that you're lying and it will make it sound worse than it probably is.  What she wants is reassurance that you still find her attractive.  Here are a few options that don't include lying or insulting her, and do include reassurance.

- Say the old cut was your favorite, but she's always attractive in general 
  ("Long was my favorite, but you're always beautiful to me.")
- Pick one thing about this cut that is flattering and focus on that. ("I really 
  like the fringe -- it shows your eyes.")

Do remember the haircut choice was based on her own taste and lifestyle, just as yours is.  As for asking her to have a specific cut (as suggested above), I would tread lightly. It's ok to say "I love the way you look when..." - but watch her reaction and consider what you're asking of her.  Would you like someone to make a similar level of change to your appearance or expense or effort?  If not, don't do it!

Also, I wouldn't ask "do you like it?" as a substitute for answering.  That makes it very clear that you don't like it.  You might as well just answer.

Regarding the information that she didn't ask - if you still like her and want her to keep liking you, try these:

- Ask if she got her haircut, then follow the above advice after she reacts.
- Don't say anything about the cut, just comment on things you actually like.

If you're just friends and she hasn't directly asked, just don't say anything. It isn't necessary.  If you're very very close friends and you feel she would be offended by you saying nothing, you can still follow the above advice.

Comment: +1 I usually say something along the lines of "I like it! I really liked it when it was long, but I like it this way too." They usually understand what I mean without getting offended.

Comment: @ncalmbeblpaicr0011, JessicaM: why dance around and sugarcoat with things you don't mean though? Can't you just say "I like the long hair better!" or something like that? It's infinitely less painful than "no, I don't like your current style" and it's just as accurate...

Comment: @Mehrdad - Sure, "I like the long hair better" is fine if you've been asked.  Originally I thought it was a romantic situation, so that puts more emphasis on making sure she knows you still find her attractive.  But, as she's just a friend, that's not so important.

Answer (score 30):

**Short answer: You don't**

You are in no way responsible or do you have any say in this (or any) women's decisions in regards to her hair, nails, or anything else. If she wanted your opinion she would have asked before it happened. If she asks you what you think about it now she is not asking for your opinion she is asking for a compliment.

There is absolutely no reason to force your negative opinion on her if she doesn't explicitly ask for your opinion. If you do not like it the best case scenario would to be to ignore it, but if she explicitly asks you what you think of her haircut then I think a good answer would be:

> I think you look (Insert flattering adjective here), as always.

because you do not have to explicitly tell her that you like the haircut (which you dont) but you also are not going to hurt her feelings by telling her the you do not like her style choices.

If you end up in a relationship, or a similarly important role in her life, then you can consider asking her to grow it out if that is what you prefer. Keep in mind that it is always 100% her decision though.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the OP is asking about situations where he has actually been asked to comment on the new appearance. If so, I don't think this answer works, but if not, I fully agree.

Answer (score 19):

I feel the problem with such questions, even more so with women, is that they can have many meanings, from "Really just your honest opinion about my hair" to "Do you think I'm generally attractive?" to even "Do you (still) care about/love me?". You need to know the person to understand the question that is being asked, and answer that.

It's OK to tell honestly if you don't like the new hairdo, even if the other person is a bit hurt – a sane person should be able to accept that other people have different viewpoints, especially if they asked for them. But you can still turn the situation into a positive one by addressing the underlying questions and feelings.

As a direct person, it's also fair if you don't want to play that game. In many situations I would probably a tongue-in-cheek answer that I'd like it longer, so it's easier to pull. In a way, you give a "male" answer to a "female" question to make clear you're not interested in playing by someone else's rules, and don't want to be dragged into that conversation.

Comment: I 100% agree with this.  You need to have a bit of personal insight to know if they are looking for a compliment, or honest feedback.  A good start would be to consider if you usually sugarcoat things around the particular person, or if in general you are quite upfront about how you feel.  If you're often sugarcoating things, they probably want you to say it looks great.  If you are usually honest, they probably are expecting your honest feedback.  The dynamics between any two people will be different.

Answer (score 12):

Lying is a socially acceptable choice in these situations. The person who has had their haircut has had a visible change in their life that they themselves notice and may be feeling self conscious about. Wondering what people are thinking or feeling, what are people saying behind their back.

If they ask, "what do you think of my hair?" Then what they may really be saying is, "You have not yet commented on my hair, and until you do I will believe you think badly of me"

People have a tendency to fill in lack of information to their own detriment in many cases.

So saying, "I like it" and then perhaps following up with a question (good compliment practice..) of "Where did you get it done?" is letting them know that you have noticed, acknowledged the change in their appearance and brought your friendship back to a state where they are not worrying over the lack of information.

Saying that you like their hair when in fact you do not but it does not change your opinion of them as a person is not necessarily harmful. If their appearance does effect your opinion of them as a person then your friendship has different issues.

So, to summarise. In interactions what people say or ask and what they mean can be different things. They are not asking you if they like your hair, they just want you to acknowledge it. 
You are then to fulfil your end of that social contract with a positive reinforcement so normal friendship can resume.

Comment: I don't think this universally applies.  Some people want honest opinions, not to be lied to for the sake of their feelings.  In this scenario you're giving them false information on what you like.  In the case where it's a woman you're attracted to, if anything were to happen moving forward, you may have misled her on what you prefer.  It would probably have to come out eventually.

Comment: If your attraction or friendship is based solely on their hairstyle then any future relationship has problems anyway, as both hairstyles and tastes change with time. if OP is a hairstylist then their opinion on the persons hair could be educated and based more than on their own taste. If not then why risk damaging someones confidence in their appearance when your opinion doesn't matter and is changeable? I think it far better to build friends up, especially in what should be a low risk interaction. However I think Bradley's answering with a question is far more elegant.

Comment: I'm not saying that the friendship or attraction is based solely on hairstyle.  It clearly _is_ a factor in the attractiveness to OP though.  Lying about what you find attractive to someone you are interested in would set them up with false expectations, especially if they ask for your opinion because they are also attracted to you.  On the flip side, I wouldn't want to be friends with someone who couldn't accept my honest opinion.  You don't have to be _harsh_, but you should be honest.  Any real friend would respect that.

Comment: We obviously have different social contracts with our friends. There are times when our honest opinions are wanted, and there are times when we are fulfilling social obligations or looking beyond what the person is asking and instead reading subtext. Being honest 100% of the time because 'honesty = good' so must be respected removes what I see as an obligation towards kindness/consideration of another persons feelings. I think friendship goes in both directions, not just 'respect my opinion' but also 'respect my feelings'. not all groups of friends are the same as this site highlights

Comment: I just don't find it particularly _respectful_ to lie to someone as a rule of thumb.  If the person seems extremely self-conscious and reacts poorly to any hint of criticism, obviously you have to tailor your approach.  At the same time, there is not much benefit to being the guy who always responds with "it looks great" when someone solicits your opinion.  At that point your opinion carries no weight.  If you have a reputation for being honest, your opinion will have a lot more weight, so when you say "Wow, that looks great!" the person will actually be able to gauge your opinion.

Comment: The point of my answer, however, was to highlight that the question 'do you like my hair?' is not necessarily what is being asked. To answer that question directly/honestly is not necessarily the best approach especially if there is any risk to their confidence. The whole point of my answer was to look at the subtext as there in lies the interpersonal skill and the fulfilment of social contracts and obligations. Being honest is not necessarily a skillful way of dealing with this interpersonal issue, as it may not actually address the matter at hand (acknowledgement of the change in appearance)

Comment: The whole point of my comments is to point out that this approach is heavily based on the specific scenario.  Lying is not always the socially acceptable choice, and there are definite risks you take by doing so.  I'm not saying this doesn't have value (I didn't vote for this answer either way), but it is not all-encompassing as an answer; and my even hurt the relationship in the long run (depending entirely on the social dynamics).

Comment: @Strawberry You can be positive without lying.  I don't suggest saying "I don't like it."  But making it clear that _personally_ you prefer longer hair does have benefits.  This can be especially helpful if you aren't a good liar, and saying "it looks great!" may come across as clearly faking it.  Saying "I do prefer longer hair; but it looks good on you!" is a very honest approach that shouldn't lead to any worse reactions than a lie.  It's personal though.  I'd rather have a reputation for honesty than a reputation for saying what you think others want to hear.

Comment: @Strawberry That's fine.  I'm just giving my perspective.  Someone who only has positive things to say, or only negative things to say, isn't really giving a useful opinion.  You have to gauge if the person is only looking for a compliment, or actual feedback.  If you're always just telling white lies to be as positive as possible, people wont take any stock in what you say.  I do not think it's safe to say it's blanket advice.  _Not everyone is fishing for compliments._  Personally, if I ask for feedback on something, I don't want you to ignore the negatives.

Comment: -1 for `Lying is a socially acceptable choice in these situations.` - The OP has made it pretty clear, I believe, that the act of lying is bothering him a lot. It may well be socially acceptable, but there are people who make an active choice not to lie, even in the sense we are talking about here (where it's all about taste, opinion etc. anyways, not "objective" lies).

Comment: @AnoE this is an interpersonal skills board for people looking to improve their interpersonal skills. He has said that telling the truth has not worked out well for him either. Recognising times when interactions should be low risk and lying is appropriate and socially acceptable response is a handy skill to learn as well as understanding subtext.

Comment: @KevPrice, then we'll have to agree to disagree. I do not particularly wish to convince you or anyone; I was just commenting to let you know the reason of the downvote. Some people, including the OP, presumably, *do not want to lie as a matter of fact,* and either are incapable to pull it off, or made an active choice not to. I believe the OP made this clear. Encouraging him to lie in a circumstance that can easily be resolved without lying should not be the first line of advice...

Comment: @AnoE that's fair. Re-reading I think they may have edited the question since my response, (difficult to check on the app) however I still think it's a valid option that should be considered

Answer (score 11):

You liking her hair is *your* problem and *your* perspective on *your* physical attraction to females.

I would normally respond to "Do your like my hair?" with:

> Do you like it?

if they reply with "Yes", then I would normally say:

> That's all that matters, what I think doesn't matter, you're awesome either way (if you think she's awesome that is).

---

This way, you're not lying by saying that you don't like her hair, so you won't relive previous negative experiences but you're still giving them an honest response by telling them that you like *them*, moreover their hair.

but if they do persist and say "But seriously, do you like it?" or if you prefer not to say what I suggested previously, then just go straight to the honest approach below:

> I preferred when it was a little longer.

She can't expect everyone to like her hair, but you're not saying you outright dislike it, but you **shouldn't have to lie**, your friendship should be stronger than a compliment on her hair, or her expecting you to lie to her.

or even better from @JMac in the comments (if you still find them attractive, but from the question you're not that shallow), you could say:

> I preferred it when it was a little longer, but you're pulling it off.

"You're pulling it off" could be translated to "it suits you" or "it looks good on you" or what I like to say is "You're rocking it" (but that could be stemmed from the US/UK mainly).

Comment: Assuming you still find them attractive, you could also go with "I preferred it when it was a little longer, but you're pulling it off."  Compliments them, and shows that it's a _personal_ preference for longer hair.

Comment: Sorry but english is not my mother langauge and I do not understand what "pulling it off" means (separate verbs aren't easily found in dictionaries). Other than that, awesome answer. I would never have thought of that !

Comment: @Bregalad edited it to add a couple more ways of saying it

Comment: @Bregalad I was worried "pulling it off" was too idiomatic; I just couldn't think of another casual way to say it.

Comment: The first one, to me, sounds extremely deflective.

Comment: @WeckarE. it really does depend on your tone of voice, I think.

Comment: When a girl asks you what you think of something, answering with "if you like it yourself that's all that matters" is just another way of saying "looks horrible, but I'm not going to be the one pointing that out for your". Better just say you preferred her previous style than moving around the subject when she brings it up herself.

Comment: she made it his problem when she asked him...

Comment: "You liking her hair is your problem and your perspective" True, but the problem is that _she asked for his perspective_.

Answer (score 5):

If I don't know what to say right away when the person asks, I won't (white) lie anyway. I'll carefully look at the person, even step back a little, ask him/her to twist around. Not only you really pay attention to what she/he did, but your have also more time to think of *how you can say things*.

**It's really different. Let me see, give me a few seconds please.**

So I can pinpoint what's really different and why. Only then, when I made my mind, I would only emphasize the "new" things that the new haircut has done, and tell her/him what I see and like:

- I already loved the way you smile, and because of [ difference A ], it makes your smile even more bright and nice.
- I like the [ blue / brown / green ] of your eyes, and because of [ difference B ], this color has more depth, and your look is highlighted.
- I like the way one can see your earrings now, good choice putting your hair behind your ears.

**Be positive about the new haircut and the new style.**
If you don't really like it, others may like it, and your friend **DO** like it most of the time, so be it... :)

Comment: If asked directly, you can also find something to say about the haircut's effect on their overall appearance such as "it makes your face look (more angular/rounder)" or "it makes you look (older/younger)" or something along those lines, if you think that they'll appreciate it. Most people who get a shorter haircut get it based on the overall appearance of hair+head+face, not just the hair by itself.

Comment: Fold. Muck. Whatever you call it. But I would definitely avoid the *angular/rounder* or *older/younger* with **any** lady though :)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where you are from, the answer could vary widely due to cultural differences, so take what I say as a Briton's take on the situation.

Comment on the hair cut, but don't say whether you like or not initially. E.g. "Is that a new hair cut?" You allow her to make first comment on it, as they will possibly say "Yeah, I was getting tired of [feature of previous style]" or possibly say that it's not exactly what they wanted.

If they say the former you can start by saying "I liked [feature of previous style]" and then go on to say how they look like a totally different person without them.

Or, you could always go for something generic, a few examples (style change | response):

- Long hair to short hair | You look more mature
- Changed hair colour | It makes you look like [celebrity they like]
- Short hair to long hair | Makes you look younger

At the end of the day, when it comes to styles and fashion, you either like it, you lie, or you get on well enough that you can insult the person's style without them getting offended.

Comment: "Is that a new hair cut?" sounds like a dumb question when it's obviously there...

Comment: @Bregalad It's quite common for people to ask "Is that a new haircut" or "Have you done something new with your hair" at least around the parts of the UK I'm from

Comment: You do realise that "You look more mature" = "Hey granny,  you're getting really old" ;)

Comment: @Geliormth that depends on the person's age(group), as age was never implied. For an 18 year old, more mature is good. For a 40 year old, mature is bad.

Comment: @Bregalad https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/how-should-one-respond-to-trivial-obvious-questions

Answer (score 3):

There's another option: You could say

> I like you no matter what haircut you have!

(since you stated that's true) and you might add

> You're your own person and the important thing is that *you* feel good with the new hair. So, if I may ask: how does it make you feel?

It may just be a question about hair but it may just as well be a question about themselves. If you get the sense that the real question is "Do you like me?", try answering that honestly and enthusiastically (since you said you *do* like them).

Answer (score 3):

## Respond to the topic, not the question

Don't take the question too literally. People often say things that need to be translated, so to speak. A simple example is:

> Literal question: "Good morning. How are you?"
>
> Literal answer (bad): "I have a headache and my mother is dying of cancer."

Instead of responding to the literal question, try to understand the purpose of the utterance.

> Underlying question: "Please acknowledge my presence and give me an overall indication of your mood so I can interact with you."
>
> Appropriate answer: "I'm good! How are you?"

Hopefully, this is clear, it's very basic to social skills-- answering literally is almost never a good idea with pleasantries like this one.

### About her hair

So now let's talk about hair:

> Literal question: "How do you like my new hair?"
>
> Literal answer (bad): "I hate it. I like long hair."

Yeah, there is no reason to put anyone through that.  Here's how I would interpret it:

> Underlying question: "Please acknowledge that you noticed my hair, and that it is socially appropriate, so I don't need to be insecure about it."
>
> Appropriate answer: "Cool, looks like you're doing the Emma Watson thing. Pulling...it...off!!!"

This isn't really lying, and honestly, you're not dodging the (real) question either.

Here are a few more examples:

> "Looking pretty sharp!"
>
> "Well that ought to catch the eye of {name of potential mate she is interested in}!"
>
> "That looks like it will be so much more comfortable in this heat! Whew! Did you know it was 108 degrees yesterday?"

The nice thing about that last example is that it also changes the topic, getting you out of a potentially awkward conversation.

### What if she truly wants your personal opinion?

This is actually rare, but it does come up sometimes, for example, if she has an important interview or other event and needs true feedback.

You should *always* verify that this is the case:

> Do you really want my honest answer?

And you should always soften the blow. The way to soften the blow with criticism is with to attribute the cause to something that is external or global, as opposed to something that is specifically always her fault. For example:

> A lot of people like it, but it's not my thing

(i.e. it's me, not you)

> It's decent, but I've seen you with better haircuts for sure

(i.e. it's this specific cut, it's not your sense of style in general)

Comment: I think your opening is overly simplistic. There's a big difference between telling someone that your mom is dying and telling them you are good. Saying "I'm really tired, my son keeps waking up all night!. " or "I'm doing ok" is more honest but not so forthcoming that the other person feels like you need to talk.  Also, your connection with the person effects this response.

Comment: If the goal of somebody saying "Good morning! How are you?" is partly to get "an overall indication of your mood so I can interact with you", how could it possibly be appropriate to say "I'm good!" when what you mean is "I'm feeling terrible!"?

Comment: The first example is a bit of an (humorous) exaggeration to make a point. I agree it is simplistic. My main point is that the bare truth is not appropriate. @David "I'm good!" indicates you are good to interact. If you are not good to interact, you might say something like, "I've got a lot going on," or simply, "Busy! Need something?" which gives the appropriate feedback for your colleague so he can weigh the importance of his need to interact against your availability.

Comment: In case you want/need to be honest, do make it very clear that your opinion is about YOU, not about HER.

Comment: @David Richerby saying "I'm good" actually means "I am willing to interact with you like I would if I was feeling good" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can **compliment them without lying**

Find something positive to say, not about your own feelings.

You could say that the haircut is fashionable, lighter, darker, expressive, fun. **Saying something positive isn't a lie, unless you claim to be feeling something when you're not**

**Appearances aren't just to entertain other people** Do you wear clothes, get haircuts, just to make others happy? I expect probably not. Maybe you just like your shirt, jeans, shoes, etc. Maybe you don't care. **Maybe your friend chose her haircut because she liked it, not to make others happy**

[Article: Why Women Have to Care About Their Looks](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/wander-woman/201107/why-women-have-care-about-their-looks)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it wasn't asked (directly or indirectly), it's not *necessary* to give your opinion.

But, if you interact with that person and wants to give her a thing that won't cost you a thing and will make her feel good. then go on and say something nice about the new haircut. Except in few cases, she chose the new style, though it would look good or great, and might be expecting to have (positive) reactions that will improve her mood.

So, say something like "your new haircut is good", "I like your new haircut", "oh, I see that you just changed your hair", and smile.

Answer (score 1):

1. If she asks, be honest, as in "I don't care for it.  In my personal opinion, I think women are more attractive with long hair."

   - If she's a sane human being, that'll be the end of the conversation
     and you can judge whether she values your opinion in the months to
     follow.
   - If she blows up at you for giving your opinion when asked for it,
     then you know she may be the type of irrational person that is prone
     to insanity.
2. If she doesn't ask, continue about your day.

   - Only irrational people put words and meanings into others' mouths. 
     If she assumes like/dislike without asking you such, she is
     overthinking the situation.
   - If she wants your opinion or is shamelessly fishing for a compliment,
     she'll ask.  Refer to #1 at that point.
3. If you're married to her, forget #1 and #2.  Preemptively strike with, "Please refer to paragraph 4, line 32 of our prenuptial.  I look forward to our nightly relations until your hair grows back."

Comment: Have you ever met another human?

Answer (score 0):

Say, "The best hairstyle ever."  Then she says, "Really?"
"Yeah, it's good."  She will know whether you like it or not.  Trust me.

When you marry her and she cooks and says, "Do you like it?"  You say, "It's my favorite."  You say that every time.  Tell your kids that every meal she makes is their favorite

Or, you can never get married, and you can never be happily married.

You should be able to find something redeeming about what they did.  You're not that difficult to be around are you?

Oh, by the way, who cares what you like.  It is not about you.

Source:  Married a long time.  Worked and been around females for a long time.

Comment: You might want to edit and add in a comment on your source. It sounds like you've been in relationships before and in similar situations.

Comment: "Comment on you source"?  I'm not sure what you mean.  Sorry.

Comment: He means you should add in your post why do answer this way. He thinks you've been in relationships, and it's worth to put in the first line "I've been in several relationships, and blahblahblah". Stating that will greatly increase the credibility of your answer, because you've been through relationship, and should've known what works and what won't work!

Answer (score 0):

A lot would depend on your willingness to be insincere. Let us assume you are not a convincing liar and she will find you out if you do lie about it.

Solution A: you lie and say you like the new 'short cut' -- she thinks you are insincere. If you later tell her something truthfully she may choose not to believe you.

Solution B: you are honest and tell her you don't really like the new haircut (however nicely you say it, as advised in earlier answers) -- she does **not** think you are insincere, whatever *else* she may think. It is a step towards establishing your general credibility but you must be consistently honest to maintain the impression.

Now it is a question of whether you want to be perceived by her as honest or insincere.

If you don't mind being perceived by her as insincere you can go ahead and lie and tell her you like it. (This is what I would do with somebody who is not close to me and who is not important to me, *in order to avoid unpleasantness.*) However, I should not lie to anyone who matters a lot to me. ***In my experience, being understood to be perfectly, even painfully honest is far preferable to being thought insincere, in the long run.***

But if she does not ask for your opinion it is better not to bring up the subject.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're asked "How do you like the way I look?" most often it's not even a question, but fishing for compliments. Even if it's not fishing for compliments, then asker is looking for your support of the decision, to validate it, and not for fair judgement.

If you genuinely find that person pretty and can express it, then focus on that. Phrase it something like "a pretty person looks pretty in every haircut" so you'll compliment the person (what could be the point) and avoid the feature you don't like. Never express dislike, even when pressed further. At most say "I really liked the previous one". This avoids saying the bad thing, and replaces it with a good thing. Even if the good thing is no more, it still was a good thing.

Attractiveness is a very complicated thing. Our brains trick us to believe that the primary purpose of maintaining own image is to "express oneself", while it has no other purpose than to attract potential partners. When you're giving your honest opinion, you're basically asking to sacrifice his/hers "personalized" look only to cater to the needs of a single person - you. That's why your personal opinion rarely actually matters here.

For this reason, you should also try to set your personal preferences aside, and try to objectively find good things. Eg. that short hair make one look younger or that the fake nails are going well with wearer's eyes. If you have nothing good to say, you can at least say that the change was "refreshing". If you have the time to prepare, you can get a crash course on recent fashion, to ready rock-solid arguments why this new haircut is so hot right now. You may come out as a fashion guru : )

Answer (score -1):

You can tell her in this way:
If there are two types of haircut say A and B and she has the A now but you like the B, then, tell her in this way:

> You are looking very nice. I think you'll look extraordinary(or any cool adjective for girls' beauty) if you have a haircut B.

**I tried it more than three times to a female friend and co-worker. Every time it worked more than I expected.**
She reacted in such a way that she appreciated my opinion. 
Because my way of telling her about changing her haircut expresses that I care for her. 
If a girl thinks something is impeding her looking good, she must change that thing.

[image]

Comment: Can you please expand on this answer to explain why this is a good option? Have you tried it yourself? How has the person reacted? Answers here should be based on experience or (if available) supporting evidence. Answers that don't explain themselves are likely to be downvoted and deleted as "not an answer".

Comment: Thanks for completely missing the point of my question. Those 2 pics are almost identical. I was talking about cutting hair length from 80cm down to 4cm in my question.

Comment: I edited my previous answer. Is it okay now? @Catija

Comment: More improved answer is a step in the right direction, so I upvotes!